# How to exclude values from an array if the values in a corresponding column are below a certain value in python?

Tags: python

I have an excel spreadsheet with 2 columns of data, both show a range of values that are both positive and negative. I want to create an array of values from the second column where the corresponding values in column 1 are below 5. How would i go about doing this?

I have attached an example set of data

[image: length data]

What i want to try to do is exclude values from the length data where the corresponding temp data is lower than 5.

i can create an array that excludes values above a threshold from the same column (using the filter function) but i dont know how to do this for a corresponding columnn

Comment: if the answer is fine now pls accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read your excel in a pandas df and then filter:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("yourFile.xlsx")
```

Then you filter:

```
result = data[data["temp"]<5]
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. is there another way?

Comment: Can you post the error statement?

Comment: there isn't an error statement. when I used this it returned the data ok but nothing was excluded.

Comment: where is the difference in that from your desired output? can you explain further?

Comment: shouldn't it be `result = data[data["temp"]<5]` ?

Comment: OK I edited the answer. If it works you may accept it pls